# How can I pass variables from view to controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, variable-assignment

I have a Codeigniter view which does some processing and creates some variables which I need in my controller.

How can I access the variables created in my view from my controller? 
Is it even possible to do so?

I can pass variables from the controller to the view, 
Can I pass variables back from the view to the controller?
Just to make things more clear. I have a main controller which takes multiple views and forms a complete page. In this complete page I just need to pass some data. This data is again, don't flame or blame me for this, is processed in a view. Now I need to set up meta data, title keywords etc, for every page which is set by a main controller method `setPageMetaData` and it accepts a key value pair. For some pages its easy to  `setPageMetaData` inside controller but in one particular case the title and keywords are generated by some processing in view. I need that information in my controller. My question was regardless of this particular case, can I pass variables from View to my Controller? Is it even possible? I could have added, "is it recommended?" to earn some applauses.

Comment: you can pull data using post of even URI segments, you can use AJAX too. Give us more details about how you really want it which would make it more clear to help u.

Comment: Also, What are *viewModel*'s, and, what Models are you referring to? A model is used to interact with an external data source (e.g. Database) you **never** load a view from a model.

Comment: @Hailwood: There are situations where you can call the model from the view through a small, lean layer: the ViewModel. I tend to go that route myself too.

Comment: Kumar, if you explain what you're *really* trying to do, we can give you some guidance on accomplishing it. You should not have any need to pass data from view to controller.

Comment: @BerryLangerak: Hailwood is talking about loading views *from* Models, which the OP is actually not even talking about. There was a mistaken edit to his post. OP seems to be loading a view as a way to retrieve or set some data in the controller, probably used to using `include`s.

Comment: I understand all the anger expressed by senior SO citizens about horrible condition of view processing some data and passing it back to controller. In real world there are chances of a horrible code written by some one else and part of your job is to maintain and develop further using the same code base. Why would some one develop on the horrible code base is another point of discussion. I somehow solved it by setting a config item in view and then using it later in the controller. But what I dont understand here is the reason to downvote w/out explanation.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: Yes, but I was simply answering his question "Also, What are *ViewModels*. That's it ;)

Answer (score 4):

Think of it like this:

- Controller = Input (including URLs)
- Model = Processing (talks to the controller)
- View = Output (what the users see after processing data)

Try to move your code to the appropriate layer instead of mixing it all up. Your view layer should only be receiving data from the controller and not processing it.

If you just need some static data, consider moving it to a [config](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) file. If you are processing some data, do this in the Model or Controller layer, read the result, set some variables accordingly, and send them to the view.

Comment: Exactly. There should be no HTML or SQL in your controller. No HTML or input handling/view processing in your model, and no SQL or data processing in your view. I have had to clean up bugs in a project where the dev didnt understand what an MVC was, and it was torture.

Answer (score 3):

You can use URI segments or Js, Ajax to help too. Simple if you use CRUD it's give controller load to do code in models.

Answer (score 1):

In Code Igniter if you are trying to pass something out of your view back to a controller you are doing something **horribly**, *horribly*, **horribly** wrong.

The only scenario for this is if your view is doing some processing itself.

Repeat after me;
**I *Rajendra Prasad Panchat* promise I will *never* Do any processing in my views**

This completely breaks the purpose of using a framework like Code Igniter.

The purpose of a [view](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) is to output your *already processed* data as a webpage.

--
Feel free to post your code and we can tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: @Roman: He thought another user was you for some reason. Kind of weird. Took me a minute to figure out, I figured it was latin for "I promise" :D

Comment: Wow, Either I was tired or Kumars Name changed :P, either that or the system glitched, strangely enough there is actually (http://stackoverflow.com/users/797124/rajendra-prasad-panchati) a user on stack overflow by that name, but he has no questions, answers, or even comments, so I have no Idea where I got that name from!